# Temp DB not getting empty

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a situation where initially the space of temp db is 8mb only.I have created a temp table say #ABC. Filled with some data.Now space of temp db is 400 mb. after i dropped #ABC the temp db is not getting to 8mb.It has still 400 mb space.what i need to get it to 8mb.

I am asking this question because  i am facing a situation where temp db completely takes all memory of hard drive(500GB) after deleting the temp table's in ssrs.I really need to solve this and i need to restart the sql server each time to release the space.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does your database have snapshot isolation enabled?  You can check by running this query on the server `select name, snapshot_isolation_state_desc from sys.databases`.  If the value is "ON" then the issue could be that you have long running transactions that cause the snapshot data to keep building and building and never release old row versions.

Comment: Here is a good reference of things you can also check: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/how-to-identify-which-query-is-filling-up-the-tempdb-transaction-log

Comment: @BateTech Thankyou for above link and reply . i have checked , only master and msdb is ON and other all DataBase including report server database it is OFF. Have I to turn them OFF for msdb and master? I am also going through link's you provided :).

Comment: No, you do not want to change the setting for the system databases, since they likely have internal logic that relies on snapshot. So we've ruled snapshot out.  Do you have any big index rebuild jobs that run on a schedule or any large data loads/ETL jobs on this server?  Any massive queries across large tables (certain operations are run in tempdb such as sorting, some joins, etc.)? 500GB is generally a very large amount of data for tempdb to taking up. Just to make certain, the 500 **GB** drive size is not a typo is it? (I only ask b/c you list the tempdb size as only 400 **MB**)

Comment: @BateTech Yes ,very very long query with many intermediate temp tables(3 lakh rows in table ).one temp table gives result to another temp table and so on and each temp table use order by and group by.In the end I drop all temp tables.I have tried `select * from tempdb.sys.objects` I have not found my any temp table there.But tempdb size not goes down.

Comment: Yes,It takes 500G complete and i can not even fire select query.

Comment: The reason you won't see any tables when looking at sys.objects in tempdb is that temp tables are locally scoped to each connection (and sometimes a more narrow scope, for example if created within a procedure then the temp table is only available within that proc).  This msdn article has some good information along with some queries you can run to check things out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176029%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @BateTech Thanks for all your suugestion's .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the operating systems files holding tempdb, these do not Auto Shrink by default and most people would think that was a bad idea.

If your process needs all that space to do it's work, then you should give it sufficient space to do so.  Shrinking will only postpone the issue as next time the process runs it will need to get that same amount of space again.  It might fail or go into a death spiral if free space has shrunk inbetween runs.